# Recovering files from SSD using DDRescue

Tags: ddrescue

I'm not sure if the SSD with lost partitions and errors can be recovered as is, it is sdc that I need to recover files from but it has no partition id like sdb which has sdb1 ntfs.

I use this command and it is executing but I'm not sure it should be done in it's current state.

```
sudo ddrescue -d -f /dev/sdc /dev/sdb clone.logfile
```

**Partitions**

```
sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL

sda             119.2G                                    
├─sda1 vfat       512M /boot/efi                          
└─sda2 ext4     118.7G /                                  
sdb               1.8T                                    
└─sdb1 ntfs       1.8T /media/me/TOSHIBA EXT            TOSHIBA EXT
sdc             931.5G                                    
sr0              1024M
```

Does this work or do I need to assign an id or something else before using DDRescue?

Comment: I hope that your `sdb` doesn't have anything important, because you are overwriting it with data read from `sdc`. (And you shouldn't leave any of `sdb`'s partitions/filesystems mounted if you want to just overwrite it.)